# Ajax load breaks prevent default

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have this script to edit WP posts with an ACF form.

On success I'm then reloading content but with the below this only works alternately

So the first time, on submit, the data saves and then the content reloads fine. On the second time the data saves but then the whole page reloads as if it's breaking the prevent default.

I know I need to reset or do something similar after each submit and load but can't figure this out.

Thanks

```
(function($) {
    //// Get the current page

    var pathtopage = window.location.pathname;

    //// Save data on submit

    acf.do_action('ready', $('body'));
    $('form#modalAjaxTrying').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    acf.add_action('submit', function($form) {
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.href,
            method: 'post',
            data: $form.serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                 acf.validation.toggle($form, 'unlock');

                //// On Success reload content

                $('#content').load(pathtopage + ' #content');
           } 
        });
    });

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Does `$('form#modalAjaxTrying')` (btw, the 'form' part of that selector is unnecessary) exist as a child of `#content`?  If so, your ajax success is replacing it, and the submit binding you put on the one that was removed will no longer exist.  If that is indeed the case, you should look into delegate binding on the submit handler.  Ref. http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @ Taplar. Yep your right it is a child, I'll look into event delegation now, any ideas how my above markup may change adding this to the submit handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's with the ACF? Why not just

```js
function() {
  var pathtopage = window.location.pathname;

  $('form#modalAjaxTrying').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: window.location.href,
      method: 'post',
      data: $form.serialize(),
      success: function(data) {
        acf.validation.toggle($form, 'unlock');
        $('#content').load(pathtopage + ' #content'); // this also boggles the mind
      }
    });
  });

})
```

But why do Ajax in the first page when you "reload" the page anyway?
Also if the new content contains the form, then you lose the event handler and need to [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: The Ajax parts saves the data from my form input, then my reload shows the new data in the content area. Yes looks like I need to look into delegate, any ideas how my markup might change adding this in? Thanks

Comment: But why do Ajax at all? Just submit the form since you reload content anyway

Comment: Delegation: `$("#content").on("submit","#modalAjaxTrying",function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $.ajax.... });`